# Styling in next js

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js

In order to style a next js app, do I really have to `import styles from "./stylesheet.css"` and add class with `className={styles.aClassName}`?

if so, what if I want to style an element by Id or TagName?

Is there a way to style like a normal react app? ie. `import "./stylesheet.css"` & `className="aClassName"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add [global stylesheet](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet).

Answer (score 0):

You can also place your stylesheet.css in the public folder and refer to it from any component.

```
<Head>
<link href="/stylesheet.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</Head>
```

Then you can use the `className="stylename"` format anywhere in your component.